# Compare two lists and print the next element using loops

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
list1=['lo0','lo1','te123','te234']
list2=['lo0','first','lo1','second','lo2','third','te123','fourth']
```

I want to write a python code to print the next element of list2 where item of list1 is present in list2,else write "no-match",i.e, I want the output as:

```
first
second
no-match
fourth
```

I came up with the following code:

```
for i1 in range(len(list2)):
        for i2 in range(len(list1)):
            if list1[i2]==rlist2[i1]:
                 desc.write(list2[i1+1])
                 desc.write('\n')
```

but it gives the output as:

```
first
second
fourth
```

and I cannot figure how to induce "no-match" where the elements aren't present in list2. Please guide! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=['lo0','lo1','te123','te234']
list2=['lo0','first','l01','second','lo2','third','te123','fourth']

for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        print('no-match')
    else:
        print(list2[list2.index(i)+1])
```

alternatively you could include a try, except to include a routine if the item is the last value in list2.

```
list1=['lo0','lo1','te123','te234','fourth']
list2=['lo0','first','l01','second','lo2','third','te123','fourth']

for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        print('no-match')
    else:
        try:            
            print(list2[list2.index(i)+1])
        except IndexError:
            print(str(i)+" is last item in the list2")
```

Comment: No, what it does is it compares every element of list1 with every element of list2, and prints no-match for every non-equal element, i.e the output is a lot of no-match and some matching strings which isn't my requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *enumerate* with a *set* to test for *membership*, if you find an element that is in the set then print the next element from list2 using the current elements index + 1:

```
list1=['lo0','lo1','te123','te234',"tel23"]
list2=['lo0','first','l01','second','lo2','third','te123','fourth']
st = set(list1)

# set start to one to always be one index ahead
for ind, ele in enumerate(list2, start=1):
    # if we get a match and it is not the last element from list2
    # print the following element.
    if ele in st and ind < len(list2):
        print(list2[ind])
    else:
        print("No match")
```

The correct answer is also:

```
first
No match
second
No match
No match
No match
fourth
No match
```

`'l01'` is not equal to `'lo1'`, you also cannot use index as if you had repeated words, you would always get the first match.

To match your own logic with the double for loops and doing  O(n^*2) comparisons:

```
for ind, ele in enumerate(list2, start=1):
    for ele2 in list1:
        if ele == ele2 and ind < len(list2):
            print(list2[ind])
        else:
            print("No match")
```

Comment: it compares every element of list1 with every element of list2, and prints no-match for every non-equal element, i.e the output is a lot of no-match and some matching strings. It doesn't give the output according to my requirement.

Comment: @Anjali, iyour required output is wrong `first, second,fourth` where is `'l01'` in list1`?

Comment: Then what I see in my answer seems pretty correct. Is this part of some assignment?

Answer (score 0):

```
list1=['lo0','lo1','te123','te234']
list2=['lo0','first','lo1','second','lo2','third','te123','fourth']
res=[]
for elm in list1:
    if elm in list2:
        print list2[list2.index(elm)+1]
    else : 
        print 'No match'
```

Out put :

```
first
second
fourth
No match
```